# React.js router different background image

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to apply background image for specific component.

I used react-router-dom and my code is below.

[App.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './components/Home';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Login.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               Login
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

[Login.css]

```
html {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Home.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Home
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

[Home.css]

```
html {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I set the background-color of Login to red and Home to blue.

But not only `Login.js` but also `Home.js`'s background color is blue.

How can I set the different background color for each components?

Answer (score 4):

Apply styles to class

Assign a class to the outermost div in Login.js

```html
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login">
               Login
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Now apply styles to the classes

```css
.home{
    background-color:blue;
    }

.login{
  background-color:red;
  }
```

If u want to apply background image for full page try this css..

```css
.home {
    background: url("image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, It's a different matter, I apply background: url("image.jpg"). But It doesn't filled full screen. After height: 100%, is also doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the css to:

```
body {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

The background color property is set to the body tag, not the html tag. The `!important` will ensure that this style is applied over any other conflicts you may have.

### --Edit--

To apply background colors to the individual components, you should add a class to each of the parent `div`, and style that class directly like so:

*Note: Heights have been added to the styles to ensure 100% vertical fill of the browser, as per the OP's request. It is not required otherwise.*

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="scene_login">
               Login
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

**Login.css**

```
body, html {
     height: 100%;
}

.scene_login {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="scene__home">
                Home
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

**Home.css**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.scene__home {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What about giving different `background-color` to different components which seems to be what the question is about.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for this. I took the original approach of changing the body background colour as it looked as if this is what the OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: @TPHughes Works fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: @TPHughes Anyway, It's a different matter, I apply background: url("image.jpg"). But It doesn't filled full screen. After height: 100%, is also doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional CSS that will ensure that the `div` is stretching to full height